# Capybara 'drag & drop' does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, cucumber, capybara

I am using cucumber/capybara/selenium/firefox on Mac. All working great except for d&d. Drag and drop is available via `drag_node.drag_to(drop_node)`. When called, it does not raise any errors but the actual drag and drop just never happens.

Now rather than copy pasting bits and pieces, I've found [this sample app](https://github.com/kbaum/dragdrop.git) (written by a guy who apparently had similar problems) that demonstrates the issue.

Google however isn't aware of `drag_to()` being broken. As far as I could see. That gives a hope that it is me missing something rather than a bug. So what is it? What am I missing? A bug?

Answer (score 8):

For me, `#drag_to` did work, however, its powers seem to be limited.

In order to move a UI-sortable table row down, I had to create a table with three rows, then run this code (in a Cucumber step):

```
element = find('tbody tr:nth-child(1)')
target = find('tbody tr:nth-child(3)')

element.drag_to target
```

This would swap the first with the second row. My interpretation is that Capybara does not drag far enough, so I gave it a target beyond my actual target.

*Note: I have configured UI-sortable with `tolerance: 'pointer`'.*

Comment: After wrestled with this issue quite a bit, this answer saved me! Thanks! This worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

I have had the same proble and solved it by going directly to the selenium-webdriver.

I an using selenium-webdriver 2.20.0 and Capybara 1.1.2

this works with this HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Cabybara Drag And Drop</title>
    </style>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
      #list_1 { background:#2C4999; }
      #list_2 { background:#99752A; }
      .list { padding:10px; width:200px; }
      .item { background:#FFF; margin:10px; }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $().ready(function(){
        $( "#list_1" ).sortable({ connectWith:"#list_2" });
        $( "#list_2" ).sortable({ connectWith:"#list_1" });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ol id='list_1' class='list'>
      <li id='item_1' class='item'>Item 1</li>
      <li id='item_2' class='item'>Item 2</li>
      <li id='item_3' class='item'>Item 3</li>
      <li id='item_4' class='item'>Item 4</li>
      <li id='item_5' class='item'>Item 5</li>
    </ol>
    <ol id='list_2' class='list'>
      <li id='item_6' class='item'>Item 6</li>
      <li id='item_7' class='item'>Item 7</li>
      <li id='item_8' class='item'>Item 8</li>
      <li id='item_9' class='item'>Item 9</li>
      <li id='item_10' class='item'>Item 10</li>
    </ol>

  </body>
</html>
```

Now fore the Ruby code.
Getting at the selenium-webdriver from capybara call page.driver.browser

```ruby
require 'test_helper'

class DragDropTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  setup do
    Capybara.current_driver = Capybara.javascript_driver # :selenium by default
  end

  def test_drag_item_1_to_list_2
    visit '/drag_drop'
    element = page.find(:id, 'item_1')
    target  = page.find(:id, 'list_2')

    selenium_webdriver = page.driver.browser
    selenium_webdriver.mouse.down(element.native)
    selenium_webdriver.mouse.move_to(target.native, 0, 10)
    selenium_webdriver.mouse.up
    sleep 2
  end
end
```

Comment: This does not fix the problem sadly (since the problem is in selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 1):

It is selenium-webdriver having problem with sortable lists. This post covers the workaround: http://www.dixis.com/?p=626

Answer (score 1):

`#drag_to` does not work on sortable lists, presumably since you aren't dragging "to" an element as much as dragging a set distance and direction. Selenium's `#drag_by` is what you're looking for but is not currently supported by Capybara.

See also:

https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/222

https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/119

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me:

```
def drag_n_drop(item:, location:)
  # this is from Selenium
  page.driver.browser.action.click_and_hold(item.native).perform

  # this is from Capybara
  item.drag_to(location)
end
```

Background:

- the page I'm testing uses the SortableJS library (https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable)
- Rspec + Capybara + Selenium Chrome (headless)

WARNING: I discovered this by trial-and-error, and I'm actually not sure why it works. YMMV and use at your own risk.